Maintain heap property without locks or version numbers or mark bits
A toy model of the problem I'm playing with goes like so:

Initialize a max heap with 2^n children and 2^(n+1)-1 nodes.
Spawn some threads.
Threads repeatedly decrement randomly-chosen leaf nodes, and then recursively update parent values by computing the maximum of the two children, stopping once a parent is found with no updates necessary
Goal is to maintain heap property

The following code achieves this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>  // for int8_t

// Global heap array
int8_t arr[64];
// Marker array to indicate if a node is being updated
atomic_int updating[64];

// Function to find the parent index in the heap
int parent_index(int i) {
    return i / 2;
}

// Function to find the left child index in the heap
int left_child_index(int i) {
    return 2 * i;
}

// Function to find the right child index in the heap
int right_child_index(int i) {
    return 2 * i + 1;
}

// Thread function to randomly decrement a leaf and update the heap
void* thread_function(void* arg) {
    for (int update_count = 0; update_count < 500000; update_count++) {
        // Randomly select a leaf node (nodes 32 to 63 in a heap array)
        int leaf = 32 + rand() % 32;

        // Atomically decrement the selected leaf node
        atomic_fetch_sub(&arr[leaf], leaf - 32);

        // Traverse upwards to update the parents
        int idx = leaf;
        while (idx > 1) {
            int parent = parent_index(idx);
            int left = left_child_index(parent);
            int right = right_child_index(parent);

            // Attempt to mark the parent node for updating
            int expected = 0;
            if (atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&updating[parent], &expected, 1)) {
                // Load the current values of left and right children atomically
                int left_val = atomic_load(&arr[left]);
                int right_val = (right < 64) ? atomic_load(&arr[right]) : INT_MIN;

                // Calculate the correct maximum value for the parent
                int new_val = (left_val > right_val) ? left_val : right_val;

                // Update the parent's value if necessary
                atomic_store(&arr[parent], new_val);

                // Mark the update as complete
                atomic_store(&updating[parent], 0);
            } else {
                // If the parent is being updated by another thread, stop further updates
                break;
            }

            // Move up the tree
            idx = parent;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

// Function to verify that each parent is the maximum of its children
void verify_heap() {
    int valid = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {  // Only check parent nodes (1 to 31)
        int left = left_child_index(i);
        int right = right_child_index(i);

        // Skip if we are at the last parent (which might only have one child)
        if (right >= 64) continue;

        // Check if the parent value is the maximum of its children
        if (arr[i] != (arr[left] > arr[right] ? arr[left] : arr[right])) {
            printf("Heap violation at index %d: arr[%d] = %d, but arr[%d] = %d and arr[%d] = %d\n",
                   i, i, arr[i], left, arr[left], right, arr[right]);
            valid = 0;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        printf("Heap property is maintained correctly.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Heap property violated.\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    // Seed random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Initialize the array, leaving arr[0] empty and setting others to INT_MAX
    arr[0] = 0;  // or leave uninitialized
    for (int i = 1; i < 64; i++) {
        arr[i] = INT8_MAX;
    }

    // Initialize marker array to zero
    for (int i = 1; i < 64; i++) {
        atomic_init(&updating[i], 0);
    }

    // Create threads
    const int NUM_THREADS = 16;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_function, NULL);
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // Print the heap array after thread operations
    printf("Heap after thread operations:\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < 64; i++) {
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }

    // Verify the heap property
    verify_heap();

    return 0;
}

I'm looking for a way to achieve this without locks, or version numbers, or mark bits, or really anything except for the heap itself. Is this possible? On x86-64, I mean.

Some x86-64 CPUs have hardware support for transactional memory.  (I think that's still a thing on some models even after microcode updates disabled part of it for security reasons, at least if you ask the OS to enable it.)  So that can be good for low-contention scenarios.  Or were you looking to only use portable 16-byte atomic load / store / RMW ops that any CPU can do efficiently (especially with AVX for 16-byte pure-load/pure-store atomicity.)
